# Comparing cell value with worksheet's name not working as expected

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing some test comparing a value in a cell with the worksheet's name.
The value in `Cells(2,1)` is `5`, and the worksheet's name is also `5`.

```
Sub test()    
    MsgBox (Cells(2, 1) & ActiveSheet.Name)

    If Cells(2, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Name Then
        MsgBox ("They are the same")
    End If
End Sub
```

I got the pop-out box saying `55`, meaning that the two values are the same, but the *"The are the same"* window never came. I wonder what might be missing here?

Comment: `Cells(2', 1).Value` may be numeric and `ActiveSheet.Name` is String. Try with either entering 5 as text in Cells(2,1) Or use `Value(ActiveSheet.Name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cell value is a number and sheet name is a string. Convert the number into a string using `CStr` before you compare against the sheet name.

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox (Cells(2, 1) & ActiveSheet.Name)

    If CStr(Cells(2, 1).Value) = ActiveSheet.Name Then
        MsgBox "They are the same"
    End If
End Sub
```